# Ghostscript merge print jobs

Tags: printing, merge, ghostscript, jobs, collect

Dear Ghostscript Gurus.

I have installed and tuned system printer to print to PDF by Gs (gswin32c.exe).
The arguments of printer's port are:

```
gswin32c.exe @"pdfwrite.txt" -sOutputFile="c:\PathToPDFFiles\%b.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f -
```

And its all right, but now I need to collect or group several print jobs together.
How can I make It with GhostScript?

### Can I make it directly from ports arguments?

Regards.
Voot

Answer (score 0):

You can send multiple files to GS on the command line, but other than that, its not clear to me what you're asking. The command line above seems to take input from stdin, not sure how you're getting that to do anything on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. You are completely right, I'v stdin printjob to GS, redirecting it from other printer by RedMon. And now how I can redirect this command to another GS command to collect several files to one. GS not understand "|"- operator.

Comment: As long as you keep sending it input on stidin, GS will keep collecting it and outputting to the same file, the problem doesn't seem to me to be Ghostscript, but more the way you are using it. If you cannot keep sending data on stdin then you need to store the segments as separate files and then execute Ghostscript with all the files specified on the command line. The way you are running GS (printing from the app and using the Port Monitor) there isn't any other choice, as each print job is a separate process in the Operating System.